# Binding data in Hyperlink Column of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, hyperlink

I have an ArrayList called `customerArrayList` to bind a GridView. Normally when I bind the data into Template Column, I use **Eval** to read and display the data from ArrayList Datasource and it works.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Address">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Customer.Address1") %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

But how can I bind the data into Hyperlink Column? When I use the following code, it gives me an error.

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Customer Name" DataTextField="Customer.CustomerName" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CustomerPage.aspx?funcName=fromSearch&customerID={0}"
DataNavigateUrlField="Customer.CustomerID" />
```

> A field or property with the name was not found on the selected data source

I think this line is giving me error:

`DataTextField="Customer.CustomerName"`

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: are you sure there is Customer column inside table Customer

Comment: have you checked the output of your data source does it contains a field called customername

Comment: @sansknwoledge Yes it has `CustomerName`.

Comment: Are you using a DataGrid or GridView? asp:HyperLinkColumn is for a DataGrid

Comment: what about simply using `CustomerName` ?

Comment: @HansDerks I am using DataGrid.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad I have already tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: In that case even `Text='<%# Eval("Customer.CustomerName") %>` in the `hyperlink` isn't working?

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad It won't work because System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperlinkColumn does not have a DataBinding Event.

Comment: i think rameezahmedsayad is telling that you can have a label field with databound field and enclose it inside html anchor tag or simply a html anchor tag surrounding databound field

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">           
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" />
            <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="CustomerID"                  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="CustomerPage.aspx?funcName=fromSearch&customerID={0}"
                DataTextField="Customer Name" NavigateUrl="CustomerPage.aspx" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datafield" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

OR Play On Grid_RowDataBound() event.

thanks